# turn awk command into an awk script (multiple F)

Tags: awk, scripting

I have a working command

```
awk  -F '[)#/(:]' 'BEGIN  { fw="";dev=""} {if ($0~/sh failover/) fw=$1 ; if (($0~/This host/)||($0~/Other host/)) dev=$2; if ($0~/\)\:/) {print $2,$1,fw, dev} }' OFS="|" test_data
```

I would like to turn it into a script. When doing so...

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
BEGIN  {F='[)#/(:]'; FS = "\n"; RS = ""; OFS = "|";fw="";dev=""} 
{
    if ($0~/sh failover/) fw=$1 ; 
    if (($0~/This host/)||($0~/Other host/)) dev=$2; 
    if ($0~/\)\:/) {
        print $2,$1,fw, dev
        } 
}' test_data
```

...the F='[)#/(:]' results in an error.

```
[...srv01]$ ./test
./test: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./test: line 3: `BEGIN  {F='[)#/(:]'; FS = "\n"; RS = ""; OFS = "|";fw="";dev=""} '
[...srv01]$
```

When changing to double quotes it takes everything between the twp double quotes as separator so will look for )#/(: instead of **)** or **#** or **/** or **(** or **:**

Here is the file content of test_data

```
[...srv01]$ cat test_data
JoeASA# sh failover | i \)\:|host
        This host: Primary - Active
                  admin Interface management (313.13.0.13): Normal (Monitored)
                  DMZ-FW Interface Inside (310.13.19.7): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  DMZ-FW Interface Outside-Zone2 (912.168.119.7): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  ENET Interface OUTSIDE(912.168.191.7): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  ENET Interface dmarc (912.168.192.7): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  GW Interface Extranet (912.168.23.27): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  GW Interface Outside-Zone (912.168.123.27): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  GW Interface management (331.1.1.47): Normal (Not-Monitored)
        Other host: Secondary - Standby Ready
                  admin Interface management (313.13.0.12): Normal (Monitored)
                  DMZ-FW Interface Inside (310.13.19.6): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  DMZ-FW Interface Outside-Zone2 (912.168.119.6): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  ENET Interface OUTSIDE(912.168.191.6): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  ENET Interface dmarc (912.168.192.6): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  GW Interface Extranet (912.168.23.26): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  GW Interface Outside-Zone (912.168.123.26): Normal (Not-Monitored)
                  GW Interface management (331.1.1.46): Normal (Not-Monitored)          
SIMPLEASA1/sec/act#  sh failover | i \)\:|host
        This host: Secondary - Active
                  Interface Edge (912.168.22.17): Normal (Monitored)
                  Interface Inside (310.13.19.17): Normal (Monitored)
                  Interface EXT (912.168.50.17): Normal (Monitored)
                  Interface WIFI (912.168.11.17): Normal (Monitored)
        Other host: Primary - Standby Ready
                  Interface Edge (912.168.22.16): Normal (Monitored)
                  Interface Inside (310.13.19.16): Normal (Monitored)
                  Interface EXT (912.168.50.16): Normal (Monitored)
                  Interface WIFI (912.168.11.16): Normal (Monitored)                      
[..srv01]$
```

Comment: Using double quotes is correct, but the input field separator variable is `FS`, not `F`. It's unclear why you suddenly set `FS` to a newline and why you set `RS` to an empty string.  This is not what your first command uses.

Comment: Thanks!  This was it....I needed that clarification with the FS (field separator). RS was just leftover from editing and trying different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the script to awk as a single-quoted string from the shell, but you seem to have single quotes *inside* the script, too. They actually end the quoted string:

```
awk 'BEGIN  {F='[)#/(:]'; FS = "\n"; RS = ""; OFS = "|";fw="";dev=""} 
                ^^^^^^^ not quoted
```

The shell sees an unquoted `)`, which causes a syntax error. Not that you'd want to use single quotes in the awk script anyway, they would be a syntax error *in awk*. So use double-quotes instead, as you did for the other assignments, they fit inside single-quotes in the shell nicely, and actually work in awk code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { foo="bar"; ...}'
```

Then, note that what the `-F` option to awk, does is to set the field separator, which is the variable `FS`, not `F`. So, you want to have `BEGIN { FS="[)#/(:]"; ...`, and you probably don't want to change the default record separator `RS` either — at least you didn't change it in your one-liner above.

---

Also, instead of putting an awk script inside a shell script, you could just skip the shell, and make awk the interpreter of that script directly (assuming your awk is at `/usr/bin/awk`):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS="[)#/(:]"; OFS="|"; fw=""; dev=""} 
{
    if ( $0 ~ /sh failover/ ) fw=$1 ; 
    if (($0 ~ /This host/) || ($0 ~ /Other host/)) dev=$2; 
    if ( $0 ~ /\)\:/ ) {
        print $2, $1, fw, dev
    } 
}
```

If that's called `./script.awk` and made executable, you can then run it as `./script.awk filename`, i.e. with the file to process as argument to the script.